# XML duplicate values - PHP

Tags: php, xml, document

Good evening!

Please can someone guide me on how to add a child with same value into one. I have this XML file: https://wpcoder.co.uk//links/sir_prakash_webdev1/ws7/currency.xml

As you can see that EUR currency has been using in many different countries i.e.:

```xml
<currency code="EUR">
    <ccode>EUR</ccode>
    <cname>Euro</cname>
    <cntry>CYPRUS</cntry>
    <crate>1.199119</crate>
</currency>
<currency code="EUR">
    <ccode>EUR</ccode>
    <cname>Euro</cname>
    <cntry>ANDORRA</cntry>
    <crate>1.199119</crate>
</currency>
```

So what I want is to add countries that are using same currency (USD, EUR, etc.) into single child i.e., [image]

My current code where I am generating that XML document is:

```
<?php 

$iso_curr_xml = simplexml_load_file("curr_old.xml");

$rates_json_url = file_get_contents("https://freecurrencyapi.net/api/v2/latest?apikey=4392e6c0-67d6-11ec-82cc-4d7a41b7625b&base_currency=GBP");

$rate_json_obj = json_decode($rates_json_url);

$ts = $rate_json_obj->query->timestamp;

$currencies = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><currencies ts="'.$ts.'" />');

foreach($iso_curr_xml as $xml_parse) {
    foreach($xml_parse as $xml_res) {
        $crcode = $xml_res->Ccy;
        $currency = $currencies->addChild('currency');
        $currency->addAttribute('code', $xml_res->Ccy);
        $currency->addChild( 'ccode', $xml_res->Ccy );
        $currency->addChild( 'cname', $xml_res->CcyNm );
        $currency->addChild( 'cntry', $xml_res->CtryNm );
        $currency->addChild( 'crate', $rate_json_obj->data->$crcode );
    }
}
$currencies->asXML("currency.xml");
```

Sorry, the least I know is that I think I need to xPath, but don't know how. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can regroup in an array (using the same key), before to write the XML :

```php
$iso_curr_xml = simplexml_load_file('https://wpcoder.co.uk//links/sir_prakash_webdev1/ws7/curr_old.xml');
$rates_json_url = file_get_contents('https://freecurrencyapi.net/api/v2/latest?apikey=4392e6c0-67d6-11ec-82cc-4d7a41b7625b&base_currency=GBP');

$rate_json_obj = json_decode($rates_json_url);
$ts = $rate_json_obj->query->timestamp;


// Regroup by crcode :

$codes = [];
foreach ($iso_curr_xml->CcyTbl->CcyNtry as $xml_res) {
    $crcode = (string)$xml_res->Ccy;

    // if the key doesn't exists, get shared data 
    if (!isset($codes[$crcode])) {
        $codes[$crcode]['ccode'] = (string)$xml_res->Ccy;
        $codes[$crcode]['cname'] = (string)$xml_res->CcyNm;
        $codes[$crcode]['crate'] = $rate_json_obj->data->{$crcode} ?? 0;
    }

    // in all cases, add country name
    $codes[$crcode]['cntry'][] = (string)$xml_res->CtryNm;
}

// Now, generate the XML (based on the previous array) :

$currencies = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><currencies ts="' . $ts . '" />');
foreach ($codes as $crcode => $data) {
    $currency = $currencies->addChild('currency');
    $currency->addAttribute('code', $crcode);
    $currency->addChild('ccode', $data['ccode']);
    $currency->addChild('cname', $data['cname']);
    $currency->addChild('cntry', implode(', ', $data['cntry'])); // implode countries
    $currency->addChild('cname', $data['crate']);
}
$currencies->asXML('currency.xml');
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<currencies ts="1642451660">
   <currency code="AFN">
      <ccode>AFN</ccode>
      <cname>Afghani</cname>
      <cntry>AFGHANISTAN</cntry>
      <cname>143.232437</cname>
   </currency>
   <currency code="EUR">
      <ccode>EUR</ccode>
      <cname>Euro</cname>
      <cntry>ÅLAND ISLANDS, ANDORRA, AUSTRIA, BELGIUM, CYPRUS, ESTONIA, EUROPEAN UNION, FINLAND, FRANCE, FRENCH GUIANA, FRENCH SOUTHERN TERRITORIES (THE), GERMANY, GREECE, GUADELOUPE, HOLY SEE (THE), IRELAND, ITALY, LATVIA, LITHUANIA, LUXEMBOURG, MALTA, MARTINIQUE, MAYOTTE, MONACO, MONTENEGRO, NETHERLANDS (THE), PORTUGAL, RÉUNION, SAINT BARTHÉLEMY, SAINT MARTIN (FRENCH PART), SAINT PIERRE AND MIQUELON, SAN MARINO, SLOVAKIA, SLOVENIA, SPAIN</cntry>
      <cname>1.198999</cname>
   </currency>
   <!-- ... -->
</currencies>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is now emptying the generated XML document. Please can you kindly check? https://wpcoder.co.uk//links/sir_prakash_webdev1/ws7/currency.xml

Comment: Look at the code, the XML source is this URL.

Comment: Please kindly look, this is the real XML document using which I am generating a new  XML with currency rates: https://wpcoder.co.uk//links/sir_prakash_webdev1/ws7/curr_old.xml

Comment: ...totally different :) But, the principle remains the same, even if the XML is different. I'll check it.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the "cur_old.xml" file.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. Kind regards